# Income from android apps

Tags: android, google-play, ads

After making quite a few android apps for myself (just for fun), I've decided to make an app to put on the google play store. I know it will be a lot of work, so I don't want to make it for free. I realize that chances are I will make little to no money.

The thing is, I would prefer putting it up for free rather than setting a price. I suppose one way to make money is to put adds and such. What is the best service for this? Are there other ways to make money?

Also, is there certain stuff that needs to be done differently in order to get your app in the play store, than when I'm just developing for myself?

Any insight into any of these would be appreciated. I am not looking to become rich, just want to see what possibilities there are to taking my hobby to the next level.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about making money and not really about programming.

Comment: Very sorry for down voting but the question, whilst valid for a developer, is really off-topic for SO.

Comment: @kha Don't really see why this is off topic: 'Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers'. At it's core it's a question about SDKs and services relating to Android, the motivation of which may be money but surely lots of professionals use this site and ask questions relating to their job, and generally people have jobs to make money.

Comment: Fair enough. Matter of opinion then. In my opinion, it looks to be off-topic.

Comment: @IanNewson : Sorry, but I agree with MysticMagic and kha - this is not a good question for SO. Asking general questions such as *"What is the best service for this? Are there other ways to make money?"* and *"...is there certain stuff that needs to be done differently..."* can, at the very least be a reason to close this question as either being "Too Broad" or "Primarily opinion-based".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beside In-App purchase suggestion, I am presenting a list of 25 Ad-SDK which are popular among the community and you can consider :

But before presenting anything kindly make a note for **Admob** as given in [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/ads.html), it is depricated

> Legacy AdMob will be shutting down on August 31, 2014. Beginning
>   August 31, you will no longer be able to use legacy AdMob to promote
>   and monetize your apps. Specifically, please be aware of the
>   following:
>
> ```
> Ads will stop serving to legacy ad units that are not updated with new ad unit IDs.
> Legacy house ad campaigns will stop serving.
> You will not be able to access the legacy AdMob UI after August 31, 2014.
> ```
>
> If you are still using legacy AdMob, please upgrade your account to
>   the new AdMob as soon as possible. Upgrading takes only 5 minutes

Now lets move on to our discussion with the ads sdk list:

1. [Google Mobile Ads](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/ads.html)

   Monetize your app with banner or interstitial ads from Google's vast pool of advertisers.
2. [Amazon Mobile ads API](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/apis/earn/mobile-ads/docs/quick-start)
3. [Startapp :](http://www.startapp.com/)

   - Ad Formats: Interstitial, Banners, Exits, Search Box and Splash Ads, 3D OfferWall
     Business Models: CPI
   - Bonus: Pay per download – if 10% of revenue earned is from InApp ads, you receive a 50% bonus on download revenue
4. [Leadbolt](http://www.leadbolt.com/) :

   - Ad Formats: Floating, Audio, In-App Alerts, Banner, Interstitials, Overlays, Videos, App Wall
   - Business Models: eCPMs, RTB, CPI, CPE
     Bonus: NA
5. [Appflood](http://appflood.com/) :

   - Ad Formats: Interstitials, More Games Menu, App Lists, Icon Ads, Notification, Custom Integration
   - Business Models: eCPMs
   - Bonus: Referral bonus is equal to 5% of whatever revenue those referred developers make on the network for the next 5 years
6. [NativeX](http://nativex.com/) :

   - Ad Formats: Banner, Interstitial, Video, Rich Media, Offerwall
   - Business Models: eCPM, CPI, CPM, CPC, CPA
   - Bonus: Guarantee will increase a partner’s U.S. in-app ad revenue by at least 30% after the first 30 days. If 30% is not reached, NativeX will pay the partner $30,000.
7. [Appia](http://www.appia.com/) :

   - Ad Formats: OfferWall, Banner
   - Business Models: CPI
   - Bonus: NA
8. [Epom Market](http://epom.com/) :

   - Ad Formats: Interstitial, Banners, Rich Media,
   - Business Models: CPC, CPM, CPA, CPL
   - Bonus: Epom Market Referral Program
9. [Airpush](http://www.airpush.com/) :

   - Ad Formats: Push, Icon, Banner, SmartWall, Rich Media, Overlay
   - Business Models: CPM, RTB
   - Bonus: NA
10. [Appwiz](http://www.appwiz.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: AppWall, Premium interstitials, Exit ads, In-app, Icon ads, Push notifications
    - Business Models: CPI, Pay Per Install
    - Bonus: NA
11. [RevMob](https://www.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: Full Screen, Link, Banner, Pop Up
    - Business Models: eCPMs
    - Bonus: Referral Scheme
12. [MobileCore](https://www.mobilecore.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: AppWall, Interstitials, Slider Ads
    - Business Models: eCPMs, CTR
    - Bonus: A $100 sign up bonus
13. [AerServ](http://www.aerserv.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: Video, Native, Banners, Virtual Currency, Rich Media
    - Business Models: CPMs
    - Bonus: Limited $250 sign up bonus
14. [Appnext](https://www.appnext.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: More Games, Notifications, Interstitial
    - Business Models: eCPM
    - Bonus: NA
15. [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: Interstitial, OfferWall, Banner
    - Business Models: CPI
    - Bonus: NA
16. [Widdit](http://www.widdit.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: Interstitial, Banners
    - Business Models: CPC, CPI
    - Bonus: $50 welcome bonus upon sign up
17. MobiMicro :

    - Ad Formats: Display Ads
    - Business Models: CPC
    - Bonus: NA
18. [AppKey](http://appkey.com/new/) :

    - Ad Formats: Banners, Interstitial, In-App Purchase
    - Business Models: CPI, CPC
    - Bonus: NA
19. [AppOptim](http://www.appoptim.com/) :

    - Ad Network Features      -  Ad Formats: Interstitial, Slide, Banner, Wall, Social
    - Business Models: CPI, CPC
    - Bonus: NA
20. [StarApplication](http://www.starapplication.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: Exit, Slide, Wall Ads, Banner, Interstitial
    - Business Models: eCPMs
    - Bonus: NA
21. [Mobicow](http://www.mobicow.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: Interstitials, Full Screen Ads
    - Business Models: CPM, eCPMs
    - Bonus: NA
22. [Pingjam](http://pingjam.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: Interstitials, Banners
    - Business Models: CPI, CPC
    - Bonus: NA
23. [TapContext](https://www.tapcontext.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: Interstitial, Banner
    - Business Models: CPC, CPM
    - Bonus: $100 sign up bonus
24. [InMobi](http://www.inmobi.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: Rich Media, Banners, Native
    - Business Models: CPC
    - Bonus: NA
25. [MiniMob](http://www.minimob.com/) :

    - Ad Formats: Interstitial, Icon, Ad Wall, Notifications, Tap-to-URL, Tap-to-Call, Tap-to-Text, Tap-to-Market
    - Business Models: CPC, CPM, CPAI
    - Bonus: NA

Comment: do you know if any of them allow the developer to press the ads in his own app? I made an app with AdMob in which I sometimes pressed ads and got blocked...

Comment: I have tried Admob, Facebook, and Startapp. So far, Admob is superior. Facebook AND startapp are at similar positions because of very very low revenue compared to Admob. But people at admob are deaf and blind. They care for nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The best for ads is admob. It is a good service and developers are earning high from it. Other ways to make income for free apps is using in-app purchases.

Answer (score 2):

Insted of focusing on what partner to get the ads from focus on the app itself and promoting it. If make a great app but a bad description, bad screenshots, not tablet support etc. you will not many downloads. When looking at making profit you have three options, you should choose the one that fits **your** app the best and not what is expected to bring most icome.

**Free with ads:**

If you are making an app that people will spend a lot of time on (such as cookie clicker games, messaging app etc) then consider ads, this will generate you income when people click on your ads. Currently I would recommend [AdMob](https://www.google.com/ads/admob/), easy to integrate and provides many type of ad banners as well as interstitial (full screen ad). Make sure not to over feed people with ads as they will uninstall your app and in most cases vote 1 star.

**Free with in app purchases:**

Free apps with in app purchases became quite popular now, they allow to purchase special credits, weapons, boosts with real money. Ads are also display in most cases and very frequently you have the message such as "Purchase any special package to remove ads forever!". This is a good idea if you are making a game, not so easy to think of ideas when making an app (example SwiftKey - buy new keyboard themes for around $1 each). Remember not to make the app useless without the purchases or pay2win if making a game.

**Paid:**

A paid app will feature the same content for each of their users, they have to pay the initial fee to download. Remember that the Play Store offers users 15 minutes after purchasing your app to remove it and get full refund! Also it is useful to note that any app / game that has in app purchases or are paid will display **your** physical address.

> Beginning September 30, 2014, to comply with consumer protection laws, you need to add a physical address to your Settings page. After you've added an address, it will be available on your app's detail page to all users on Google Play. If your physical address changes, make sure to update your information on your Settings page.
>
> If you have paid apps or apps with in-app purchases, as the seller of that content, it's mandatory to provide a physical address where you can be contacted. If you don't provide a physical address on your account, it may result in your apps being removed from the Play Store.

When you finished making your app ensure that the graphics such as the logo, screenshots and desription are to a high quality and will make users want to get that app. Other then that, there isn't much more you need to do to publish apps, an Android developer account is a one off fee of $25, cheap comparing to Apple's $100 per year.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [TapforTap SDK](https://tapfortap.com/developers/sdk) which generates dynamic adds.

Comment: The two demo videos (homepage) of this SDK 'do not exist' says YouTube. Seems unprofessional...

Comment: video is not needed.(was not in my case)
you can go through the docs and use it ....its easy...

Comment: TapForTap site has been updated since this post, and the new link to the SDK is here: http://www.tapfortap.com/download/, also, new updated videos are upcoming! (Disclaimer: I currently work for the company that bought and now owns TapForTap)

Answer (score 0):

You earn more money from [Air push](http://www.airpush.com/) rather than admob